# Nuget 2.7 ignores repositorypath when restoring packages

Tags: repository, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Since I upgraded to nuget 2.7, it is not respecting the repository path that was set in the nuget.config in my solution directory.

It only ignores it when restoring the packages, however if I add a new package it respects the repository path.

How do you make nuget restore to look for the packages in the directory specified in the repository path in my nuget.config?

Answer (score 3):

1. You are probably experiencing [this bug](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3521), which has been fixed in NuGet 2.7.2.
2. Otherwise, could it be that you are using NuGet v2.7 with a solution that was configured to use the MSBuild-integrated package restore approach of NuGet <= v2.6?

   Please follow the steps in [Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore). In short, what you should do is remove the `.nuget` folder (which contains `nuget.exe`, `nuget.config` and `nuget.targets`) from your solution, and also remove all references to `nuget.targets` from your projects.